# Change font size UITextField when pinch

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios6, uitextfield

I'm developing an iOS6 app for iPad. The user can add a textfield, edit it, move and rotate it. I would like that when the user pinches the field, it gets bigger. I've tried it, but the text gets pixeled, because the font size doesn't change. How can I detect the actual font size so as to increase it? This is my actual code:

```
- (void)pinchDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*) pinchRecognizer {
    CGFloat scale = pinchRecognizer.scale;   
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.transform, scale, scale);   
    pinchRecognizer.scale = 1.0;    
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not try this?

```
CGFloat currentFontSize = self.font.pointSize;
CGFloat newFontSize = currentFontSize * scale; //or anything you wish    
self.font = [self.font fontWithSize:newFontSize];
```

Comment: Lol, I was going to say before you edited.  Would need to be a multiple of scale.  Or even, store the font size and then adjust the font size var by the scale and then use it to set the font.